# TYPO3 TCA fill in a field with the year of creation and the UID

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have created a new field in the TCA. This is now empty. Now I would like to fill this in with the creation year and the current UID when creating the data record or afterwards.

Do I have to do this via hooks or tasks?

Answer (score 1):

As the `uid` of a new record is unknown until the record is saved there could not be a prefill.

Of course you could create a scheduler task to set a field with the value from the creation date (field `cr_date`) and `uid` regulary.

But a better solution would be a hook after the record creation as it would be less overhead.

---

On the other side: as the relevant data already is stored in every record (`cr_date` and `uid`):
**do you realy need another field with the same information?**

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.

I also did some research yesterday. And see the only sensible way to create a task.

Thank you.